# Retrieve SQL view definition from Progress 4gl database

Tags: progress-4gl

Is there a way to extract the definition of a SQL view on a Progress database? i.e. so we can ALTER the view?  We are running Progress 10.2b.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the SQL-92 engine I would expect that standard SQL tools and techniques should work.  The default interface that Progress provides is the "sqlexp" command line tool but you can use whatever you'd like (for instance, lots of people like SQuireL SQL client).

If you are referring to "embedded" SQL within the 4GL engine then you will need to use the data dictionary.  Hopefully that isn't what you're talking about because there is nothing but pain and agony to be found by trying to use SQL from the 4GL side of things.

Comment: Thanks Tom. We pull all the data from the Progress db into a SQL Server for reporting nightly (because we experienced the pain and agony you refer to connecting our reporting tool to Progress).  We use a sql view on the Progress database that mimics one in our SQL Server warehouse to get some live/production data.  This may not be a documented solution but we found this statement will get us the SQL view definition:  select * from PUB."_sysviews"    in case it helps anyone else.

Answer (score 1):

Progress views are held in `sysprogress.sysviews`. There is one row for each 2,000 characters of a view definition; a sequence row `SEQ` counts from 0 to N if you want to assemble a view by each 2,000 character piece.